# Using 'for loop' to sum nested list values and return (total of sum)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, control-flow, built-in-types

*I am receiving the count of each line in each list*, 
I am looking to sum each particular values of entire list, (Nested lists included)

`[[3],[4],][1],[3]] = * 11`  is my desired result.

**example:** *code*

```
ar1 = [
          ['jam','apple','pear'],
          ['toes','tail','pinky','liar'],
          ['aha!'],
          ['jam','apple','pear']
      ]

def function(arg1)
    heads = 0
    for i in arg1:
        heads += arg1.count(i)
        print heads
```

I have used this `print` because i dont know how to compile and debug any other for than the print statement and recheck work, so please no flaming.**(newbie alert)**

**example:** *result*

```
['jam','apple','pear']     1
['toes','tail','pinky','liar']    2
['aha!']     3
['jam','apple','pear']    4
```

I prefer a hint, or hints to what methods i should be applying or an example. I am in no way expecting a solution. I

Comment: Are you obligated to use the for loop? Unless you need to know the count for each particular line of the list, the simple route would be to flatten the list (basically, put every item of every sublist into the same level of a single list), and count the number of items in that single-level list. Here's a thread on flattening lists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: There are two conceptual problems here, both relating to the line `heads += arg1.count(i)`. First (just basic logic): what is the list that you want to process each time through the loop? It is `i`, not `arg1`.`arg1` is a list **of lists**, and using it in a `for` loop will give you each contained list one at a time. Second: what do we want to find out about that list? Answer: its **length** (number of elements). That is the value we have to add to `heads` in order to solve the problem, right? So, that is the essence of the question - making it a duplicate of the one I have linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some choices :

1.flatten your nested list and calculate the length of total list:

```
>>> len(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,ar1))
11
```

Or you can loop over your list and sum the length of all your sub-lists you can do it with a generator expression within `sum` function :

```
>>> sum(len(i) for i in ar1)
11
```

Comment: i am not allowed to use the math module. i am thinking of alternative ways. and this is my conundrum.

Comment: @CabMod so what about voting?

Comment: i just tried to vote, i don't have the minimum required reputation of 15. @Kasra

Comment: @CabMod so you can accept the answer! but if it was helpful! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case your actual data contains deeper nesting than you've shown:

```
def sum_len(lst):
    return sum(1 if not isinstance(e, list) else sum_len(e) for e in lst)

ar1 = [
          ['jam','apple','pear'],
          ['toes','tail','pinky','liar'],
          ['aha!'],
          ['jam','apple','pear']
      ]
print sum_len(ar1)  # 11

# Same elements, with arbitrary list wrapping:
ar2 = [
          [['jam','apple',['pear']]],
          [['toes',['tail','pinky'],'liar']],
          [['aha!']],
          [[['jam','apple'],'pear']]
      ]
print sum_len(ar2)  # 11
```